# Changing the lookup field format

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

How can I change the format information is presented when I use a lookup field? To be more specific, if I relate a contact to an event with a lookup field, and I click on the magnifying glass icon to look for my contact, how can I show all contacts instead of just recently used?

Comment: I dont think you can remove the recently viewed contacts when you click on the look-up icon..

Comment: I just want to show all contacts instead of recently viewed

Comment: Most users would lose productivity if it showed all contacts; the list shows you items you've recently used, and so the more you use the system, more likely it is that the contact you're looking up will already be there. This list is limited to 200 records per entity for performance reasons as well. Imagine if you had 50,000 contacts and it tried to show them all? You'd be waiting for a very long time waiting for the list to populate, all the while your list would be unusable.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported. It will always show the Recently Viewed with the ability to filter the entire set, but it will never just show all contacts. Unfortunately, it just can't be done using the standard lookup field.